# How to change the content for each option of select element with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My task here is to change the content in the table whenever the select's options change.

The code below is my solution but I don't think that is good at all. What if when the options have more than 3 options... this might lead me to modify lots of in the `if else` condition. Thus, if you have others solution, please let me know that.

Might I set `id="approve_2"` as show default with my edited JSFIDDLE?

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7us66/3/)**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="select_vehicle">
            <option value="company_vehicle">Company Vehicle</option>
            <option value="hiring_vehicle">Hiring Vehicle</option>
            <option value="taxi">Taxi</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="company_vehicle">
    <td>Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>Hiring Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr id="taxi">
    <td>Taxi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var select_vehicle = $("#select_vehicle");
// Set selected item
var set_selected_item = $(select_vehicle).val("company_vehicle");
// Hide options "Hiring Vehicle" & "Taxi"
var company_vehicle = $("#company_vehicle"); // Get id "Company Vehicle"
var hiring_vehicle = $("#hiring_vehicle"); // Get id "Hiring Vehicle"
hiring_vehicle.hide();
var taxi = $("#taxi"); // Get id "Taxi"
taxi.hide();


$(select_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
var valueSelected = this.value;
if (valueSelected == "company_vehicle") {
    company_vehicle.show();
    hiring_vehicle.hide();
    taxi.hide();
} else if (valueSelected == "hiring_vehicle") {
    company_vehicle.hide();
    hiring_vehicle.show();
    taxi.hide();
} else {
    company_vehicle.hide();
    hiring_vehicle.hide();
    taxi.show();
}
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** **http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/7us66/3/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your code without repetition like this:

```
$('table tr:gt(0)').hide();
$('#select_vehicle').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#'+val).show().siblings('tr').not(':first').hide();    
}).change();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7us66/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for your code. However, there are lots of `<tr>` tag above and below my code... Could you please tell me about this `table tr:gt(0)`?

Comment: [:gt(0)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) will match elements at an index greater than index 0 which is your first `tr`, if you want greater than second `tr` than use `:gt(1)`